# Save a complex entity using EF from JSON

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, json.net

I've been trying to save a complex entity in EF code-first using Json.NET for a couple of days without success.

**[Major edit and tl;dr;:]** Is there a way to deserialise a JSON object into an entity and keep their relationships?

**I can store it the regular way. My problem is after deserialising the object.**

By design, the `Preference`s should added to the database, but their `Value`s are foreign keys (giving a `PreferenceValue` table).

This is my model (oversimplified for brevity):

```
public class Preference {
    public virtual ICollection<PreferenceAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class PreferenceAttribute {
    public virtual ICollection<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class Value {
    public int ValueId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The values seem not to be attached to the context before saving, causing the engine to store new `Value`s instead of using the foreign keys provided by the JSON object, which looks like:

```
{
    "PreferenceAttributes":[{
        "PreferenceTypeId" : 1,
        "Values":[
            {
                "ValueId" : 1
            },
            {
                "ValueId" : 2
            },
            {
                 "ValueId" : 3
            },

        ]
    }]
}
```

I can save it whithout any problems directly in C#; the "code" I use to seed the preferences:

```
var attribute = new PreferenceAttribute {
    AttributeId = 1,
    Values = context.Values.OrderBy(a => a.ValueId).Skip(1).Take(5).ToList();
};

var preferece = new Preference {
    Attributes = new List<PreferenceAttribute> {
        attribute
    }
};

//user is fetched from "context" as well
user.Preferences.Add(preferece);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Please, keep in mind that it's just about the `Value`s. The issue is, as noted before, that new `Value`s are being added to the database instead of using their `Id`s as foreign keys to relate to `PrefferenceAttribute`s, i.e., EF is thinking that I want to add new `Value`s, like so:

```
attribute.Values = new List<Value> {
    new Value {
        ValueId = 1, //This id will be ignored by EF since it's not fetched using context; new record will be inserted;
        WhateverAttributes = "WTF"
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match up to the (simplified) version of your code, can you edit please :)

Comment: The code you are using to cast / persist the `Values` is most likely where the issue is. If you could post that code, it would be helpful.

Comment: Edited. My problem is localised on the "values" area. The code I posted is to illustrate the depth of the relationships. I already used all sorts of configurations to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is foreign key records are not referenced by existing record, instead they are newly created and referenced.

I think that issue occurs because all your entities are in Added state. You may want your foreign key records in Unchanged state.
Check this link for entity states http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

First of all, I would advice you to separate domain model from Dto. Once you do this, you are going to resolve foreign key records manually before you flush them out.

Comment: I already have my domains separated and values are recorded as foreign keys if use C#. My issue is in the process of deserialisation of the entity.

Comment: Thats because, the entity model being built from deserialization is not being tracked by EF. All of them go in the Added entity state. But when you load PreferenceAttribute and reference them, the PreferenceAttribute is Attached and in Unchanged state.

Comment: Yep. I know that. ;)
I didn't make myself clear: is there a way to deserialise an object keeping their relationships using Json.NET? I think I'll have to make my own deserialiser...

Comment: Since you already said that you got Domain model and Dto, you are going to resolve all the foreign key records manually. Trust me, you dont want the JSON.Net deserialized object being your domain model and directly handing over to EF.
If you think, its lot of code and work, try Automapper, ninject, etc

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That's the word I was actually expecting to receive from the beginning, but I thought there would be a way to do it directly Json.NET -> EF. I'll accept this as the answer, though.